# unable to connect to neptune database instance from tinkerpop

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune

I am following this guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/access-graph-gremlin-console.html to connect to my Neptune database but as mentioned in step 7 to configure Neptune endpoint `hosts: [your-neptune-endpoint]`, I was unable to connect using the cluster or reader endpoint
[image]

and unsure on what exactly is the Neptune instance endpoint. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Wherever you are running the Gremlin Console from has to have access to the VPC that Neptune is in. How were you trying to connect to Neptune and where were you connecting from (EC2, laptop, another VPC, etc.) ? Also 

A simple way to check the connectivity is to try `curl https://<neptune-endpoint>:8182/status`

Comment: What exactly is the `<neptune-endpoint>`  which are referring to?

Comment: The cluster endpoint or the reader endpoint. Make sure to use HTTPS and include the port number (8182 is the default unless you changed it to something else).